# hyperparameter search with unknown test set distribution

Tags: machine-learning, validation, hyperparameter, multi-class, f1

I'm training a 3-class neural network classifier (conv layers and softmax at the end, nothing special). Let's say, in the test set I will have N1 examples of the 1st class, N2 examples of the 2nd class and N3 examples of the 3rd class. The train set is balanced but the true test set proportion N1:N2:N3 is unknown as the test set is still being prepared by another group. The metric I'm interested in is the f1-score for the 1st class. If I find a set of hyperparameters that optimizes this metric for class proportions 1:1:1, will it also be the optimal set for any N1:N2:N3?

I guess this holds for binary classification as maximizing f1-score over the hyperparameter search space also maximizes precision and recall. This becomes clear when we take the derivative of the f1-score w.r.t. the optimized parameters: it's zero when both precision P and recall R derivatives are also zero (P'=R'=0)(or in another case when R'P^2+P'R^2=0, but it looks unlikely to satisfy). So, for a given PRC threshold, the maximum of f1-score coincides with precision maximum and recall maximum as a function of model parameters. Though the optimal PRC threshold is dataset-dependent...

But what about multiclass classification, when we have different class cross-contamination and classes 2 and 3 will contribute differently to false positives for class 1 as the proportion N2:N3 will change?

Comment: Why do the train and test sets differ? You seem to be asking "how to tune the model on the test set" which is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Because (unlikely sensitivity/recall) precision depends on the prevalence of each class, this does not even hold for the two-class case. This will in general depend a lot on the specifics of the situation, especially on whether there is a boundary area where one class is more likely but the other class(es) as still possible. The bigger this boundary area is, the more it matters that you train and evaluate with the same class proportions as in the final test set.

E.g. for image classification and some types of fraud detection, the correct answer is usually very clear and the boundary area is relatively small. In those scenarios, it is often quite unproblematic to train on different distributions (e.g. making it 50:50 because this makes it easier for the neural network to learn). In contrast, for predicting based on age, sex and blood pressure whether someone will get a myocardial infarction in the next 10 years, it will be large (it's entirely plausible that people who are according to our data completely identical get very different outcomes), in which case the covariate distribution in training and validation data matters enormously.

One idea could be to think of plausible distributions. Then, you could find hyperparameters that give a good average performance across the plausible distributions and don't result in too bad a worst-case performance.

Comment: Thank you @Björn. I think, I was a bit unclear in my question about the splits of the datasets. There is a train set which I keep balanced since classification of the minority class  is very important (though I plan to introduce class weights as hyperparams). There is a validation dataset whose class distribution should ideally follow test dataset distribution but the latter is unknown. Your point is that if I do hyperparameter search on 1:1:1 validation dataset this won't necessary give the same optimal hyperparameters as for, let's say, 1:20:100 test dataset, right?

Comment: Yes. And it might even matter what the training dataset is. Imagine a situation without any predictors and class prevalences of 1:20:100. Most models fit in 1:1:1 data will predict 0.33 for each class for new observations, while it should be the inverse of the prevalences. One can obviously correct for this, of one knows the true distribution.

Comment: Thanks again @Björn. Now it's more clear.  I guess the ratio in the training set mattes the most when we have a poor generalization. In this case, the population prior may be added through the Bayes theorem to correct for the predicted probabilities. But when we're confident about predictions, the population priors can be neglected. This falls in line with your comment: the larger the boundary area, the lower the prediction confidence, the stronger the population prior.